# Customizing jTable

Tags: java, swing, jtable

I need to customize my jTable. All I need, is to put a custom Swing object (like jButon, jPanel, etc.) into the table cell. Is it possible? I'm trying:

```
jTable.getModel.setValueAt(jPanel1,0,0)
```

and

```
jTable.getModel.setValueAt(jPanel1.getUI(),0,0)
```

But the result is only a some kind of string, representing the object...

I'm aware of custom renderers, but still don't get the technique of registering them properly. How do you do that?

Comment: take a look at this tutorial: http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#renderer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [*How to Use Tables, Concepts: Editors and Renderers*](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#editrender) in the swing tutorial. It sounds like you're getting the default renderer for `Object`, which is "rendered by a label that displays the object's string value." You can use [`setDefaultRenderer`](http://java.sun.com/javase/6/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#setDefaultRenderer%28java.lang.Class,%20javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer%29) to associate your class with your renderer, as shown in this [example](http://sites.google.com/site/drjohnbmatthews/table).

Answer (score 2):

You have to make use of a [ListCellRenderer](http://java.sun.com/j2se/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/ListCellRenderer.html) for this,
Read a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/457463/putting-jcombobox-into-jtable).

Answer (score 2):

you can visit [this webpage](http://www.java2s.com/Code/Java/Swing-Components/ButtonTableExample.htm) it's reeeeeeally helpful